# Подключить существующую виртуальную машину в VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

У меня на компе 2 диска: SSD с самой сиситемой, и HDD с фильмами, музыкой, проектами, и т.п.. В том числе на HDD диске я создал папку VirtualBox_VMs и когда создавал виртуальные машины в VirtualBox, то в эту папку их сохранял.

Сейчас я полностью переустановил ОС, затем примонтировал свой HDD-диск. Установил VirtualBox. И пытаюсь понять, как добавить существующую виртуалку. Мне почему-то казалось, что кнопка "**+ Добавить**" это то, что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но он почему-то не видит сам vdi-файлик **Xubuntu_20_04_1.vdi** (хотя он есть):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как сделать?))

Comment: `vdi` - это просто файл диска ВМ. Сам конфиг ВМ - файл с расширением `vbox`, его и надо добавлять.

Comment: Угу. Просто даблклик по .vbox и всё будет ок.

Comment: @user207200 , donRumata , спс помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Создать вм, без диска и в настройках подключить образ vdu

Comment: может быть, `vdi`?

Comment: Ну от опечаток ни кто не застрахован)